# Minimizing Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I just learned about minimizing JS to make it load quicker, so what I've been doing is copying that and putting it into the JSbeautifier. However, when I do this it comes back as like 7k lines of JS and I'm curious if this is just one function or a whole library or does it depend?

Comment: GIGO: You get out what you put in.

Comment: I get that I get what I put in, but I'm wondering if 7k lines of JavaScript makes a box drop in or rotates ads or if all that JS in there is like a CSS file and you just call part of it when needed?

Comment: Very unclear question.  Please state what you started with, what you operation you were trying to achieve, what result you achieved and what your question is about that information.

Comment: It depends on what is contained in those 7K lines of code. Only you know what functionality was included in the code you passed to the minifier.

Comment: I went in to the code in CNN.com and looked at the http://z.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.element/js/3.0/protoaculous.1.8.2.min.js to study the code and put it in the jsbeautifier and when I look and it I have absolutely no clue as to what it does or how it works

Comment: This will be gZipped as well, so probably won't make any sense even when beautified. Suggest you check out the unzipped Prototype Library source at http://www.prototypejs.org/

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of minifying the javascript is to remove any and all unnecessary line breaks and white space and in the case of a good minifyers, it will rename variables as well.

The beautifyer ADDS line breaks and white space so as to make things more readable, which means you're circumventing the whole point of minification by putting your code into the beautifier. Run the beautifier on your non-minified code to make it more readable for you and when you're ready to publish it to the web, then minify it. Minified javascript is not meant to be readable.

I usually keep a development version and a release version. I test locally and then when I upload my changes, I minify.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To minify and/or pack, you can use jscompress.com